# How do I pass a value into CLASS in DIV tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic2

I'm editing an existing code, for a Progress Bar. Initially, the progress bar can only accept progress value [min, max, progress]. For example [min=0, max=100, progress=30].

I would like to add new input that can change the color. For example, if color="yellow", the progress bar color is yellow. How do I do that?

I would like to make the CLASS value (progress-bar.html), to be changeable.

I've tried several ways, but due to lack of understanding about the syntax, I was unsuccessful.

main.html

```
<progress-bar [min]="0" [max]="100" [progress]="30" [color]="yellow">
</progress-bar>
```

progress-bar.ts

```
 export class ProgressBarComponent {

  @Input()
  progress: number;

  @Input()
  min: number;

  @Input()
  max: number;

  @Input()
  color: any;


  constructor() {
  }
```

progress-bar.html

```
<div style="display:flex;padding-bottom:5px;">
<div class="red" [style.width]="((progress/max) *100) + '%'"></div>
<div class="background-bar" [style.width]="(100-((progress/max) *100)) + '%'"></div>
```

progress-bar.scss

```
.red{
    height:10px;
    margin-top:20px;
    background-color:#E64B55;
     -webkit-transition: width 2s;
transition: width 2s;
}

.yellow{
    height:10px;
    margin-top:20px;
    background-color:#db6623;
     -webkit-transition: width 2s;
transition: width 2s;
}
.background-bar{
    height:10px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:0px;
    background-color:lightgrey;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set class={{color}} for the div you want the background color for .div class="warning {{color}}"  this color you got as input from parent component.

Comment: It did'nt work. Ive tried both class={{color}} and also class="warning{{color}}"

Comment: Give a space before {{color}} . It should be warning {{color}}. If you hardcode yellow there how can you change color when the same component is used in another template.?

Comment: Try [color]="'yellow'" where you pass the color class.

Comment: Both, class={{color} and class="warning color" can be use. The remaining stuff was the string input: [color]="'this is string'". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add more than one class to an element just by separating them with a space in the html. For example:

```
<div style="display:flex;padding-bottom:5px;">
<div class="foreground-bar-warning yellow" [style.width]="((progress/max) *100) + '%'"></div>
<div class="background-bar" [style.width]="(100-((progress/max) *100)) + '%'">
</div>
```

Adding the yellow class to the 2nd div will make it yellow.

Comment: however, it will only show the last color. If i put class="red yellow", it will show yellow, eventhough user enter color="red"

Comment: I would like to make it like this: <div class="based-on-user-input"......>